# Why i m getting Segmentation Fault in this case?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I m preaparing Sierpinski Triangle and everything works fine but it shows me Segmenation Fault and i dont know what should i change in my code.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define  t 32
#define  x 65

void display(char s[t][x])
{
  int i,j;

     for (i = 0; i < t; i++){//algorithm
         for (j = 0; j <= x ; j++){

             if ((s[i][j] == '0' && s[i][j+1] == '0' && s[i][j + 2] == '1') || (s[i][j] == '1' && s[i][j + 1] == '0' && s[i][j + 2] == '0'))
                 s[i+1][j+1] = '1';
             else
                 s[i+1][j+1] = '0';
         }
     }

    for (i = 0; i < t; i++){//printinng
        for (j = 0; j < x; j++){
            if (s[i][j] == '1') printf("X");
            else printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
  }
}
int main() {
  char sierpinski[t][x];
  int i;
  int y = (x/2);//srodek 
  for(i=0;i<x;i++){//first row
    if(i == y) sierpinski[0][i] = '1';
    else sierpinski[0][i] = '0';
  }
    display(sierpinski);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In line 11 you are exceeding the array bounds with `for (j = 0; j <= x ; j++)`, please try `for (j = 0; j < x ; j++)`. But I think even that will exceed because of the `[j+1]` and `[j+2]`indexing.

Comment: Corrected but the fault still exists. ;/

Comment: edited the comment

Comment: so that indexing is incorrect?

Comment: Well,the maximum index allowed is `x - 1`.

Comment: Yeah. Same with `i + 1`. But you can keep the indexing if you adjust your array size. An array with `n` elements has valid indices `0` through `n - 1`; `n` is just one beyond the end of the valid range.

Answer (score 4):

Just tried clang with address sanitizer on your code

```
$ clang++-9 -fsanitize=address c.cc -o test && ./test
=================================================================
==14763==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7ffd7c8ff160 at pc 0x0000004c53ea bp 0x7ffd7c8fe860 sp 0x7ffd7c8fe858
WRITE of size 1 at 0x7ffd7c8ff160 thread T0
```

It means you touch memory outside of array boundaries. Indeed in line

```
if ((s[i][j] == '0' && s[i][j+1] == '0' && s[i][j + 2] == '1') || (s[i][j] == '1' && s[i][j + 1] == '0' && s[i][j + 2] == '0'))
```

Index `j + 2` can be bigger that `x - 1`.

Comment: I tried  for (i = 1; i < t; i++){
   for (j = 1; j <= x ; j++){
    if ((s[i-1][j-1] == '0' && s[i-1][j] == '0' && s[i-1][j+1] == '1') || (s[i-1][j-1] == '1' && s[i-1][j] == '0' && s[i-1][j + 1] == '0'))

and it works

Comment: In case `j == x`, you still access `s[][j + 1]` which result it `s[][x + 1]`, which is out of boundaries. Invest some time to handle edge cases. It is good practice if you access `j + 2` to use `for(int j = 0; j + 2 < x; ++j)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check bounds in the `if` check

`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#define  t 32
#define  x 65

void display(char s[t][x])
{
  int i,j;

 for (i = 0; i < t; i++){//algorithm
     for (j = 0; j < x ; j++){
         if(j+1 < x && i+1 < t) { // Add this
            if ((s[i][j] == '0' && s[i][j+1] == '0' && s[i][j + 2] == '1') || (s[i][j] == '1' && s[i][j + 1] == '0' && s[i][j + 2] == '0'))
                 s[i+1][j+1] = '1';

            else
                 s[i+1][j+1] = '0';
         }
     }
 }

for (i = 0; i < t; i++){//printinng
    for (j = 0; j < x; j++){
        if (s[i][j] == '1') printf("X");
        else printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
 }
```

}

```
  int main() {
  char sierpinski[t][x];
  int i;
  int y = (x/2);//srodek
  for(i=0;i<x;i++){//first row
if(i == y) sierpinski[0][i] = '1';
else sierpinski[0][i] = '0';
```

}

```
 display(sierpinski);
 return 0;
```

}